# Setting up IIS with System.Data.OracleClient

Tags: asp.net, iis, oracleclient

I have a asp.net web application that connects to a Oracle 10.2g database. If I'm running my site in the Visual Studio 2008 webserver everithing is ok, but when a publish it in IIS a get "System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater".

I added all the permissions for the ASPNET, Authenticated Users and even Everyone but still doesn't work.

I have no idea what else to try. It seems clear to me that this is an IIS issue as the site works well in VS2008 integrated webserver. I'm using IIS 5.1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you define "added all the permissions"? Added the permissions to what? And have you actually installed the oracle client software on the server?

Comment: I added read,write,execute on ORACLE_HOME folder. And i have installed both Oracle Server and Oracle Client and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the Oracle client on your server.  The DLL by itself is not enough.

Your database administrator should have the client install available.  If not, it's available from [otn.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html)